# Condition based subset in R

Tags: r, if-statement, match, subset

I have 2 named numeric vectors of length 15000, `met` and `nor` where some similar names exist. for example:

```
head(met)
     ALB    IGKJ1     IGKC    IGKJ4    IGKJ2    IGHG2 
25.75415 20.55957 18.28749 17.87589 17.22944 16.60235
head(nor)
   SAA1      CRP  RNVU     SNORD68   CYP1A2     IGKJ1 
25.74548 24.05058 16.72566 15.05746 13.75348 10.74111
```

I want to subset `met` if it dose exist in `nor` and if each `met` value is `1.5*nor` bigger than its corresponding `nor` value.

in the example above, by the comparison that I want `IGKJ1` will be the only output.

How should I code this?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, e.g. the result of `dput(head(met))` and `dput(head(nor))`. Your question will have a higher chance to be answered by someone, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

# get named vectors
met = c(25.75415, 20.55957, 18.28749, 17.87589, 17.22944, 16.60235)
names(met) = c("ALB", "IGKJ1", "IGKC", "IGKJ4", "IGKJ2", "IGHG2")

nor = c(25.74548, 24.05058, 16.72566, 15.05746, 13.75348, 10.74111)
names(nor) = c("SAA1", "CRP", "RNVU", "SNORD68", "CYP1A2", "IGKJ1")

# transform them as data frames
dt_met = data.frame(v_met = met)
dt_met$names = row.names(dt_met)

dt_nor = data.frame(v_nor = nor)
dt_nor$names = row.names(dt_nor)
```

First option to keep names and both values as rows of a new dataframe:

```
# keep names as a dataset
dt_met %>%
  inner_join(dt_nor, by="names") %>%  # keep names that exist in both datsets
  filter(v_met > 1.5*v_nor) %>%       # keep rows where the condition is satisfied
  select(names, everything())         # order columns

#   names    v_met    v_nor
# 1 IGKJ1 20.55957 10.74111
```

Second option to keep only the names that pass your criteria and then use them to subset your original vector:

```
# save names as a vector
dt_met %>%
  inner_join(dt_nor, by="names") %>%  
  filter(v_met > 1.5*v_nor) %>%
  pull(names) -> new_names

# subset met using those names
met[names(met) %in% new_names]

#    IGKJ1 
# 20.55957
```

Comment: Awesome! it works fine! just for my own info, was it possible to code it into a `ifelse` @AntoniosK ?

Comment: I'm sure there's a way using ifelse, because you have to apply a condition, but not sure if it's a good application here. Filter is doing the same thing.